# How to find time(in milliseconds) difference between two linux servers?

Tags: linux, time, virtual-machine

How to find time difference between two VM(linux)?

I tried to find using "watch date" command, but it is useful if the time difference is in seconds

Comment: "Time difference between two VM" between what exactly? System clock? Packet transmission duration?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What do you want to achieve or what exactly do you want to check? Do you want to find out the precision of the time synchronization?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.